# Maximum amount of activities in app? Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there something like maximum activities in android app?
I would like to know because I am thinking to create sound app with ringtone feature. It will have roughly around 40 activities. But only 1 will be running constantly.
Is that too much? Should I find another way?

Explanation why I need 40 activities
I have 30 sounds and I want to set them as ringtone. 
1 normal activity with buttons to play Mp and stuff, and 35 other activities, 1 for each file.
What I want is to on Long click start activity with layout and there will be more buttons
I tried with contextual menu but it doesn't look good.

Comment: Activity don't stay in memory all time, so numbers isn't a problem.. but 40 activities for a ringtone feature? why not just use one activity and change update for the file when needed?

Comment: And how can I do that? Because first I need to copy file and set name of file then set as ring tone.

Comment: Just one activity and use extras to pass file name/path etc.

Comment: I see, thanks. I will look for a way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have a problem directly due to the number of activities, but I question your design. It will likely be difficult to get right and suffer performance issues and the APK will probably be very overly large.

An alternative approach could utilize the fact that you can selectively use/show different layouts for a single activity and that a single layout can selectively show different components in the the same visible space.

Comment: Size might not be too bad if most of the activities were thin extensions of a master activity class.  But I agree changing the content is superior; like there should be one Activity for each "level" of the program, and switch out the content of the "file level" one for each file.

Comment: Size and performance is not really a problem. At least not on devices with better hardware, didn't have a chance to test those devices with bad specifications. As for just switching layouts, is there like maximum lines of code in 1 activity? Something like after some number of lines app start running slower and laggy?

Comment: Your application could run on decent hardware... but what if someone install it in a bad hardware? Your application could not work/be slow.  You should consider every phone

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many activities as you want. There is no constraint on the number. All Android activities are stored in a stack and the one at the top of the stack is the one that is visible. When memory is low, the Android OS will automatically start killing the ones that are lower down the stack and are not running any background tasks or services.

Comment: There likely is a constraint - for example there is a constraint on the maximum number of methods in a single dex file.  But it is large.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is nothing documented about this by Google. I think what factors in will really depend on the type of the phone. Of course there cannot be an infinite number of activities open - all I'm saying is there is nothing like a cutoff number designed into Android.

Comment: Disagree.  Surely the number of distinct activities must be several times smaller than the maximum number of distinct methods in a file, which is a known limit.  And for that it would not matter how many are "open" - that is an actual limit on unique constructs in a dex file, regardless if they are ever executed.  The only question would be if you can spread your activities over multiple dex files - apparently using multiple dex files is quite tricky, so my suspicion would be no.

Comment: Not true, Android does not start "killing ones that are lower down the stack" https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html It will kill activities in backgrounded processes but if your app is in the foreground it wont.